# Simplest way to plot 3d sphere by python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, 3d, render

This is the simplest as I know:

```
from visual import *
ball1=sphere(pos=vector(x,y,z),radius=radius,color=color)
```

Which alternatives can you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/index.html) library for 3D visualization and some examples to draw a sphere. It should work with Python 2.7.

Enjoy!

Comment: is it simple to draw a sphere? `import mayavi.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np` + `mlab.clf()
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:11j, 0:2*np.pi:11j]
x = np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
y = np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
z = np.cos(phi)
mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
mlab.mesh(x, y, z, representation='wireframe', color=(0, 0, 0))
mlab.show()`

Comment: I got it! the is another possibility: `mlab.points3d(x, y, z, value, resolution=30)`